# How to forward and mask a URL with Google Domains/Blogger?

Tags: web, dns, blogger

I bought a domain using domains.google so that I could create a personal website/resume

Once I bought it, I realized that in order to create a website for free, I'd have to use blogger (and I don't want my website to look like a blog).

I wanted it to look something like [this](http://christopher.su) or [this](http://www.sarahlichang.com/). Squarespace looked really nice but too expensive for now (~$120 / year).

I've currently got my Google Domains linked to my blogger, and on my blogger I have (on the edit HTML page)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var d='<data:blog.url/>';
  d=d.replace(/.*\/\/[^\/]*/, '');
  location.href = 'http://owndomain.com';
</script>
```

It forwards my website to owndomain.com, but "owndomain.com" displays in the address bar, when I actually want myownwebsite.com to show there. How can I fix this?

I saw this answer [Mask forwarded blogger urls to own domain urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107593/mask-forwarded-blogger-urls-to-own-domain-urls), but I'm not sure where to put the CSS (I tried putting it right below the `<script>` in a `<style>` thing, but it didn't work)

Comment: The obfuscated domain names make this question hard to read. Is owndomain.com the Google Domains name and myownwebsite.com the name of your blogspot, or vide versa?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the theme tab inside blogger, click customize, click advanced, scroll down and click Add CSS. Then you just put your custom CSS in the box and click save.